# xtable for not supported functions (with R)

Tags: r, statistics

what am I supposed to do, if xtable doesn't know a special command. For example assume the estimation of a tobit model, like this:

`require(AER)`
`require(xtable)`

`attach(cars)`

`tob<-tobit(dist~speed)`
`summary(tob)`

`xtable(summary(tob))`

`detach(cars)`

the output of summary is pretty similar compared to an output of a linear model... What can I do, to make xtable understand, that I want to have the coefficients in a Latex table? Samme with other functions like `summary(zeroinfl(<model>))` from the pakage `pscl`?
What would you guys recommend to do?

Comment: @user734124 -- I usually pass through `coeftest()` in `lmtest` and then extract the columns I want (e.g., `coeftest(glm.object)[, c(1, 3)]`) then pass this to `xtable()`. It is isn't too limiting since I usually don't want all of the xtable output anyways and like the ability to `merge()` several regressions into one table. If I want to add N or R^2 to merged tables, I use the `add.to.row` option in `print.xtable()`.

Comment: hi Richard! Unfortunately it is not possible to use xtable(coeftest(Tobit.object)). But thanks for the Input adding rows to a table!

Comment: @user734124 -- You should be able to extract rows with `[, 1:4]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another function that you can use. It is a modified version of the xtable defined for lm.
i.e I have just modified the function xtable.summary.lm for the tobit case. 
It will also be aligned to other xtable functionalities

```
xtable.summary.tobit <- 
function (x, caption = NULL, label = NULL, align = NULL, digits = NULL, 
display = NULL, ...) 
{
 x <- data.frame(unclass(x$coef), check.names = FALSE)
 class(x) <- c("xtable", "data.frame")
 caption(x) <- caption
 label(x) <- label
 align(x) <- switch(1 + is.null(align), align, c("r", "r", 
     "r", "r", "r"))
 digits(x) <- switch(1 + is.null(digits), digits, c(0, 4, 
     4, 2, 4))
 display(x) <- switch(1 + is.null(display), display, c("s", 
     "f", "f", "f", "f"))
 return(x)
}
## Now this should give you the desired result
xtable(summary(tob))
```

Hope it helps in getting the desired result

Comment: Awesome and impressive! Thank you sayan!

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "convert it to a class xtable understands". For example,

```
tmp <- summary(tob)
str(tmp) ## a list
names(tmp) ## the contents of tmp
str(tmp$coefficients) ## the class of the coeffients table ("coeftest")
is.matrix(tmp$coefficients) # TRUE
class(tmp$coefficients) <- "matrix"
xtable(tmp$coefficients)
```